# How to remove flutter gridView spacing

Tags: flutter, gridview

I found that when I set my `crossAxisCount` to 2*n the `gridView`  will have a white divider, as soon as I start scrolling, it will flicker. If my `crossAxisCount` is 2*n+1, that won't happen, I tested the official demo as well,but I don't want these dividers, so how do I get rid of them?

2n items:

[image]

2n+1 items:

[image]

This is my code:

```
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 0,
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Its is because as first image,
There is 2 items in a row.
And In your code

> crossAxisCount :2

crossAxisCount is denoted for The number of children in the cross axis.

So,
If you  want to show lines in grid item set this exact number of items in row.
If you dont want this set zero.